# Compile Android project programmatically

Tags: android, ant, compilation, project

I want to compile an existing Android project from code.
If just type `ant debug` in my console it works, but if I try to build it from my code it fails.

I try to run the script [using the following code](http://from%20http://e-blog-java.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-call-ant-script-part-1-without.html):

```
    private static boolean runAntScript(String scriptName) {

        File buildFile = new File(scriptName);
        Project project = new Project();
        DefaultLogger myLogger = new DefaultLogger();

        project.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
        myLogger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
        myLogger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
        myLogger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
        project.addBuildListener(myLogger);

        try {
            project.fireBuildStarted();
            project.init();
            ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
            project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
            helper.parse(project, buildFile);
            project.executeTarget("debug");
            project.fireBuildFinished(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            project.fireBuildFinished(e);            
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Log (updated log is at the end):

```
Detected Java version: 1.5 in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
Detected OS: Linux
parsing buildfile /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/build.xml with URI = file:///home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest
 [property] Loading /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/local.properties
 [property] Loading /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/ant.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/ant.properties
Importing file /home/axi/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml from /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/build.xml
parsing buildfile /home/axi/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml with URI = file:///home/axi/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml
Property ${key.store} has not been set
Build sequence for target(s) `debug' is [-set-mode-check, -set-debug-files, -set-debug-mode, -debug-obfuscation-check, -setup, -build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile, -compile, -post-compile, -obfuscate, -dex, -crunch, -package-resources, -package, -do-debug, debug]
Complete build sequence is [-set-mode-check, -set-debug-files, -set-debug-mode, -debug-obfuscation-check, -setup, -build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile, -compile, -post-compile, -obfuscate, -dex, -crunch, -package-resources, -package, -do-debug, debug, uninstall, -set-instrumented-mode, install, installi, installd, -test-project-check, test, -pre-clean, emma, -release-prompt-for-password, all, -set-release-mode, -release-obfuscation-check, -release-nosign, release, help, instrument, clean, installt, installr, nodeps, ]

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-setup:
     [echo] Gathering info for AndroidCalculatorTest...

BUILD FAILED
/home/axi/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:440: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:373)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
    at at.tugraz.iaik.amd.util.CompileAnt.runAntScript(CompileAnt.java:36)
    at at.tugraz.iaik.amd.util.CompileAnt.main(CompileAnt.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ant.NewSetupTask.getVersion(NewSetupTask.java:654)
    at com.android.ant.NewSetupTask.execute(NewSetupTask.java:178)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    ... 10 more
--- Nested Exception ---
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ant.NewSetupTask.getVersion(NewSetupTask.java:654)
    at com.android.ant.NewSetupTask.execute(NewSetupTask.java:178)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
    at at.tugraz.iaik.amd.util.CompileAnt.runAntScript(CompileAnt.java:36)
    at at.tugraz.iaik.amd.util.CompileAnt.main(CompileAnt.java:15)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Call from console:

```
$ ant debug
Buildfile: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-setup:
     [echo] Gathering info for AndroidCalculatorTest...
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 16
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.2
    [setup] API level: 8
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] No library dependencies.
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] 
    [setup] WARNING: Attribute minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml (7) is lower than the project target API level (8)

-build-setup:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.

-pre-compile:

-compile:

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/classes.dex...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/res
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png => /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png => /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png => /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Crunched 3 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating AndroidCalculatorTest-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/AndroidCalculatorTest-debug.apk

debug:
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/axi/workspace/Tripwire/AndroidCalculatorTest/bin/build.prop

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 6 seconds
```

---

If I add:

```
project.setProperty("key.store", "/home/axi/.android/debug.keystore");
project.setProperty("ant.home", "/home/axi/Downloads/apache-ant-1.8.3/bin");
project.setProperty("ant.version", "Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012");
```

the problem is now:

```
/home/axi/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:445: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.ant.TaskHelper.getSdkLocation(Lorg/apache/tools/ant/Project;)Ljava/io/File;
    at com.android.ant.NewSetupTask.execute(NewSetupTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at at.tugraz.iaik.amd.util.CompileAnt.runAntScript(CompileAnt.java:44)
    at at.tugraz.iaik.amd.util.CompileAnt.main(CompileAnt.java:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding all (likely not all are needed) Android Sdk and Ant libs and tools.jar to the classpath it worked :).